# Accessing salesforce.com page from visual.force.com page

Tags: iframe

Trying to load a page with the domain salesforce.com inside an iframe hosted on a visual.force.com page but I keep getting this 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error. I've tried adding both domains to CORS (which I don't believe does anything because it needs to be on the same domain) and tried both domains in remote settings.

Is there something I need to add in apex to allow this to work?

The host page displays a custom visual force page which provides a link to enable a lightbox that places an iframe inside the lightbox.
Inside the iframe is another custom page that is using the opportunity standard controller... so it displays opportunities within the iframe as a visualforce page just fine. But this page also has links such as "[Change]" for ownership. When clicking on the link inside the iframe, it complains about same origin policy because the visual force page is on a different domain (visual.force.com) then the standard salesforce.com domain.

[image: Opera Capture]

Comment: CORS is _specifically_ designed to allow requests across domains. Can you provide more specific details about your use case and what you've tried and a copy/paste or a screenshot of the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Which page are you trying to place in the iframe? There's a variety of different "domains" that Salesforce uses, and each has different rules about how they can be used. Odds are, the page you're trying to display simply can't be displayed in a frame. Most pages are set to `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin`, so no matter what you do, it simply won't work.

Comment: Appended information to the question. I'll try and get a screenshot when I have time... but hope this is enough to go on... essentially visual.force.com can't redirect to salesforce.com.